# Comparing different Random Forest model in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am developing various Regression Random Forest Model in R, is there a way I can compare them and get their AIC score similar to linear model or should I check only the variance explained in Random Forest.

Comment: `stats::AIC` function might help.

Comment: I tried that,I am getting error while calculating AIC score of random forest models.

Comment: You can compare the OOB Error of every model. That should be sufficient.

Comment: Not sure AIC at all applies to forests. You will have a hard time estimating *k*, the effective number of parameters for a forest. RF fully embraces bootstrapping, you can do so also in your model selecting.  Check out e.g. the `carat` package

Comment: I think @Soren means the `caret` package.